# Why char * c can be assigned with a string without allocation or reference?

Tags: c++, c

```
char * c = "world"; // works fine
```

but

```
int * p = 10; // throws an error
```

it needs to be done like

```
int * p = new int(10); // in C++
int * p = (int*) malloc(1 * sizeof(*int)); // in C
```

If pointer is to be allocated to some memory or it should be referencing to some address then why a string can be stored in a character pointer without allocating memory to it, why not a integer datatype ?

Comment: `"world"` is an array of characters; `char * c` points to its beginning. `10` is just an integer.

Comment: The answer is that you're doing completely different things with `c` and `p` that's why they're different, but firstly, `char* c = "world"` is not valid in C++, only in C and in outdated C++ standards, secondly, your example using `malloc` is not equivalent because it doesn't set the value to `10`.

Comment: In C99 you can write `  int *p = (int[1]){10};` which is a nearly direct equivalent of `char *c = "world";`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C and C++ happen to provide a syntax, the string literal, for creating a value of type array of `char` with a specified initial value.

In C, the string literal `"world"` is of type `char[6]` (5 for the length of the string plus 1 for the terminating `'\0'`). In C++, it's of type `const char[6]`. The difference is for historical reasons. In either language, string literals should always be treated as read-only.

And like any expression of array type, it's implicitly converted, in most contexts, to a pointer to its first element. That's why

```
const char *c = "world";
```

is valid. The string literal `"world"` itself creates an anonymous array object, and the initialization causes `c` to point to the array object's first element.

There doesn't happen to be such a built-in syntax for creating an object of type `int`.

Well, actually there is. C99 added *compound literals*, letting you write:

```
int *p = (int[]){ 10 };
```

which creates an array object of type `int[1]`, with the same implicit conversion to `int*`. (C++ doesn't have compound literals.) (The lifetime of the array object depends on the context in which it appears; if it's inside a function body, the array ceases to exist when the enclosing block finishes. String literals, on the other hand, have *static storage duration* and exist for the entire execution of the program.)

Incidentally, this:

```
int * p = (int*) malloc(1 * sizeof(*int)); // in C
```

is incorrect; you want `int*`, not `*int`. But it's better written as:

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof *p));
```

Casting the result of `malloc` is unnecessary in C, and can hide errors in some cases. And using `sizeof *p` makes the code more robust; if you later change `p` from an `int*` to, say, a `double*`, you only have to change the type in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Because by definition, string literals have the type `char*`, the pointer to the first character of the string.

Comment: shoudn't it be a const char*?

Comment: @V-X String literals have type `char []` in C; no `const`.

Comment: Still it's always worth pointing out, that when assigning a string literal to a char pointer, type should be `const char*`, because in most modern operating systems string literals are in read-only memory segment (and even when this is not true, modifying values of literals at runtime seems... hacky).

Answer (score 1):

A Pointer variable should store address .

```
char * c = "world"; // works fine
```

because , `"world"` is assigned memory in the read-only block of the program , hence `"world"` got some address and this address is stored in pointer `c`

```
int * p = 10; // throws an error
```

because `10` is constant integer and is not allocated any memory yet , hence it has no address . We cannot store constant `10` in the pointer `p` because its not an address .

Thats why we do

```
int * p = new int(10); // in C++

int * p = (int*) malloc(1 * sizeof(int)); // in C
```

This allocates memory with value `10` to integer , and the address of that integer is stored in `p` which is correct

Comment: sorry , it should be sizeof(int).